# How to pass a variable in url in c#

Tags: c#, .net, variables, url

I am trying to pass a string into a url in C#:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
  var responseStr = client.DownloadString("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5 /weather?q=Groningen,nl&APPID=%207b030ffcc7338cc5f1adc4ca8e6205aa");          
}
```

I there a way to pass a string variable, instead of ?q=Groningen
So I could use a text field to get the weather of a city.

I could not find the answer.

Thank you

Comment: `"...q=" + yourStringVariable + "&APP..."`

Comment: Why don't you use string concatenation? Did you encounter a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# you can use `+` operator to concatenate strings.

So you can use something like following,

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
  var responseStr = client.DownloadString("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5 /weather?q="+CHOICE+",nl&APPID=%207b030ffcc7338cc5f1adc4ca8e6205aa");          
}
```

**CHOICE** is the variable with your desired location.

More on concatenate : [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I tried it before. But then the blue lined url was no longer 100%. So I thought it was not going to work. I thought i needed Request.Querie.

Answer (score 3):

You could use string concatenation to do so:

```
var url = "http://.....q="+city+"&....."; 
var responseStr = client.DownloadString(url);
```

where `city` is the variable that holds the city you want to pass.

Answer (score 0):

```
Webclient client = new Webclient();
string city = "Lahore";
string appId = "123456789";
string url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID="+appId+"&q="+city+"";
var json = client.DownloadString(json);
```

Now de-serialize josn response as per your requirement.

Either using any way below

> 1. JavaScriptSerializer
> 2. JSON.Net library
> 3. DataContractJsonSerializer